# Listview with baseadapter android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

in listview i am only getting first value repeatedly can anyone tell why such thing is happening.  the below is the calling function where the base adapter is called

```
private void dbGet(String profileType) {
        String[] projection = { "filename", "path", "created_on" };
        String selection = "profile_type=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = { profileType };
        Cursor c = sqldb.query(DatabaseHandler.file_list_table_name, projection,
            selection, selectionArgs, null, null, "id DESC");


        if (c != null && c.getCount() != 0) {
            DownloadedFileListAdapter downloadedFileListAdapter = new DownloadedFileListAdapter(
              this, c);
          listView.setAdapter(downloadedFileListAdapter);
      }
    }
```

the below is the adapter code for listview but its fetching only first value repeatedly so where am i going wrong.

```
public class DownloadedFileListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  Context mContext;
  Cursor mCursor;
  boolean movetonext = false;
  private LayoutInflater inflater;

  DownloadedFileListAdapter(Context m, Cursor c) {
      mContext = m;
      mCursor = c;
      Log.d("checking :", "in DownloadedFileListAdapter activity");
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
      return mCursor.getCount();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
      return mCursor.moveToNext();
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
      return position;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      if (inflater == null)
          inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                  .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      if (convertView == null)
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.display_file_list, null);

      TextView fileName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.downloaded_file_name);
      TextView fileCreatedOn = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.file_path_created_on);
      if( mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToFirst() ){

      fileName.setText("" + mCursor.getString(0));
      fileCreatedOn.setText("" + mCursor.getString(2));
      mCursor.moveToNext();

      }
      getItem(position);
      return convertView;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Don't use the cursor on your adapter.  Iterate the cursor first and populate a List of objects with it's content. Then send it to the adapter.

Comment: thanks and can u please share an example ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009480/convert-results-of-sqllite-cursor-to-my-object and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view

Answer (score 0):

You are using this:

```
if( mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToFirst() ){
```

if you use `moveToFirst` you will reach the first row time and again, just remove that part of the if condition.

Comment: if i remove moveToFirst from if condition then my app crashes stating CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException