# SQLite: get id from ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-sqlite

This is my first app and i'm having some problem whit ListView

How can I get the ID in the database after clicking on a Item?
I can't use position because the Id may not be continuous and even if it is in order sometimes does not return the correct Id any.

this is my code, Thank you for your help:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class livello1 extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper myDb;
Button next;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.livello1);
    populateListView();
    registerClick();
}




private  void registerClick(){
    ListView list =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {



            Intent i = new Intent(livello1.this, bossi.note.Edit.class);

            i.putExtra("id", position);

            //i.putExtra("id", id);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}

private  void populateListView(){

    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
    String[] myItems = new String[myDb.numRow()];
    int cont = 0;
    if(res.getCount() == 0){
        // show message
        return;
    }
    while( res. moveToNext()){
        myItems[cont] = res.getString(1);
        cont ++;
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.da_item, myItems);
    ListView list =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);}
```

Comment: Please, write how do will the list . That is `getView` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of solution approaches.

For example, you can store of Id's if `ArrayList` before ListView initialization.

That is, execute `"SELECT id FROM mytable"`

Then store in arraylist and use  while click method.

Example:

```
//in class declaration
private     ArrayList<Long> ar_ids = new ArrayList<Long>;



 //
        String sql = "SELECT id  FROM table";
            Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
            String out = "";
            ArrayList<Long> ar_ids = new ArrayList<Long>;
             if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                 do {

                     ar.add(cur.getString(0));
                    } while (cur.moveToNext());
                  }else{

                  }
}
        cur.close();
```

for click event:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {



            Intent i = new Intent(livello1.this, bossi.note.Edit.class);

            i.putExtra("id", ar_id.get(position));

//this is awsome!
            startActivity(i);

        }
```

and initialize this something like:

```
private void myfunc() {
    String sql = "SELECT id  FROM table";
    Cursor cur = myDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
    String out = "";
    ArrayList<Long> ar_ids = new ArrayList<Long>;
     if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
         do {

             ar.add(cur.getString(0));
            } while (cur.moveToNext());
          }else{
              throw new NullPointerException();
          }
}
cur.close();
}

private  void populateListView(){
    myfunc();
    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
    String[] myItems = new String[myDb.numRow()];
    int cont = 0;
    if(res.getCount() == 0){
        // show message
        return;
    }
    while( res. moveToNext()){
        myItems[cont] = res.getString(1);
        cont ++;
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.da_item, myItems);
    ListView list =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);}
```

Answer (score 0):

well instead of using the ArrayAdapter you can extend a **BaseAdapter** or **ListAdapter** or even the `ArrayAdapter` to make your custom adapter. First of all make a plain java class to map your database data including **id** to an object. Then make a custom **BaseAdapter** instead of using the ArrayAdapter. In your BaseAdapter class you have to override various methods including `getItem` and `getItemId` methods. Now you can return the whole mapped object from the getItem method and simply obtain the object of selected item of the ListView by using `listView.getSelectedItem()` method in the Activity or Fragment class. Once you get the object you can access the id easily.

You can find a good example and explanation of a custom adapter [here](http://abhiandroid.com/ui/baseadapter-tutorial-example.html)

About mapping the database result to an object, you can get some concept [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009480/convert-results-of-sqllite-cursor-to-my-object)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with extending `ArrayAdapter`. All those methods you mention can be overriden

Comment: I am not telling him not to extend ArrayAdapter. I am only telling him not to simply use the ArrayAdapter without extending it

Comment: anyway I have now added the ArrayAdapter too :p

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can replace you code class with this one, I have added a cursorAdapter and attached it with your ListView, in adapter I have added a method for getting Id that I call from click listener to retrieve id from cursor, you will have to set column number for _ID in `public void getId(int position)` from `MyCursorAdapter` class below.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class livello1 extends AppCompatActivity {
DatabaseHelper myDb;
Button next;
private MyCursorAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.livello1);
    populateListView();
    registerClick();
}




private  void registerClick(){
    ListView list =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked, int position, long id) {

            Intent i = new Intent(livello1.this, bossi.note.Edit.class);

            //retrieve id from cursor
        int _id = adapter.getId(position)
            i.putExtra("id", _id);

            //i.putExtra("id", id);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}

private  void populateListView(){

    Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
    adapter = new MyCursorAdapter(this, res, 0);
    ListView list =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}


//adapter for list view 
class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    Cursor cursor;

    // Default constructor
    public MyCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, flags);
        this.cursor = cursor;
    }

    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        String text = cursor.getString(1);

        //make sure the TextView id is "@+id/text1" in da_item.xml
        TextView tvText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        tvText.setText(text);
    }

    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflator inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                     Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        return Inflater.inflate(R.layout.da_item, parent, false);
    }

    public int getId(int position){
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        int colId = //set id column number here
        int id = cursor.getLong(colId);
        return id;
    }
}
```

Since the code is untested, you might face a build issue in start, but it should give an idea of what's going on in code. feel free to ask any question if you face any problem in compilation